# HTML site verification tool

Tags: css, html, w3c

I need an online tool, in which I just enter an HTML website's URL and it gives me the list of issues in it. What type of issues I need to check are:

1. 404 error and other errors like this.
2. HTML5 compatibility issues like this tag is no more being
   used in HTML5 and other errors like this.
3. CSS issues.
4. Any other issues related to HTML websites standards.

Comment: Why not  Google page speed ?

Comment: "HTML3 or HTML5" ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @Raja: What makes you think PageSpeed will address any of the issues listed?

Comment: This Question is Off-Topic! But for HTML Validation you can use: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Help-Center: 4.Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @BoltClock I wrongly understood the question ...!

Comment: @j_s_stack Problem is straight forward. We want to automate the process of HTML validation instead of wasting time when encounter the error in UAT or customer environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this validation tool from W3C.

http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: If thats the Answer ist seems like you havent made any research before Posting your Question. A short look on Google: `HTML Validation` would have been enough!